# failed install of SOAP::Data on Win 10 and Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to install SOAP::Lite under Strawberry Perl on Windows 10

```
PS C:\Strawberry\perl\bin> perl -v
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

    ...
    t/SOAP/Transport/TCP.t ....................... ok
    All tests successful.
    Files=56, Tests=895, 13 wallclock secs ( 0.20 usr +  0.22 sys =  0.42 CPU)
    Result: PASS
    Lockfile removed.
      PHRED/SOAP-Lite-1.27.tar.gz
      C:\STRAWB~2\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- OK
    Running make install for PHRED/SOAP-Lite-1.27.tar.gz
    Appending installation info to C:\STRAWB~2\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
      PHRED/SOAP-Lite-1.27.tar.gz
      C:\STRAWB~2\c\bin\gmake.exe install UNINST=1 -- OK
    Warning: optional module 'Apache' not known. Skipping.
```

I have tried to install the "optional" Apache module but nothing is found so optional doesn't appear to really mean optional in this situation.

ideas?

**Edit**

I now see thist it *is* installed in the site lib dir.  So, I just tried to install SOAP::Data.  It tries to build/install `SOAP::Lite` and "fails" as above and does not install `SOAP::Data`.

Comment: The installation appears to have worked. Is there a problem when you use SOAP::Lite? The Apache module is likely referring to the old [mod_perl version 1](https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/index.html) which you probably don't need.

Comment: `C:\STRAWB~2\c\bin\gmake.exe install UNINST=1 -- OK` indicates the installation was successful

Comment: Re "*So, I just tried to install SOAP::Data. It tries to build/install SOAP::Lite and "fails" as above and does not install SOAP::Data.*", There isn't a SOAP::Data module; SOAP::Lite, part of the SOAP-Lite distro, populates the SOAP::Data module. And again, you showed it *successfully installing SOAP-Lite*, not failing

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I was trying to `use SOAP::Data;` and when I ran my script it barfed saying that I need to install that module.  Commenti9ng that out clears that up.  Thank you all.